# Javascript quiz where a question is appearing inappropriately

Tags: javascript, forms, button, input, onkeypress

I split a 6-question form to show one question at a time, ie it turned into a quiz. The problem is the quiz is working perfectly with 5 questions, but not 6. I don't know why question 6 is appearing together with all other questions, as in the following image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jS8eM.png

If I delete question 6, the error disappears, that is, question 5 does not appear with all other questions, and the program goes back to displaying only one question at a time.

The logic of showing/hiding questions is in (1), in function nextQuestion() and in the events submit#.addEventListener(). Most likely the problem is here. But, it doesn't make sense to me that nextQuestion() works until #question-5, but not for #question-6.

All my buttons are type="button", except for the last question, which is type="submit". This had given me problems before.

**Thanks to anyone who suggests another logic and change the code completely, however, my interest is to know why this code is not working.**

**EDITED AFTER ANSWERS:** Here's the code working for anyone who might be interested:

```js
// Variables

var submit1 = document.getElementById('submit1');
var submit2 = document.getElementById('submit2');
var submit3 = document.getElementById('submit3');
var submit4 = document.getElementById('submit4');
var submit5 = document.getElementById('submit5');

var previous2 = document.getElementById('previous2');
var previous3 = document.getElementById('previous3');
var previous4 = document.getElementById('previous4');
var previous5 = document.getElementById('previous5');
var previous6 = document.getElementById('previous6');

// Next question button

submit1.addEventListener('click', function() {
    nextQuestion(2);
    growProgressBar('33.33%');
})

submit2.addEventListener('click', function() {
    nextQuestion(3);
    growProgressBar('50%');
})

submit3.addEventListener('click', function() {
    nextQuestion(4);
    growProgressBar('66.67%');
})

submit4.addEventListener('click', function() {
    nextQuestion(5);
    growProgressBar('83.33%');
})

submit5.addEventListener('click', function() {
    nextQuestion(6);
    growProgressBar('100%');
})


// grow Progress Bar

function growProgressBar(percentage_width) {
    var bar = document.getElementById('progress_bar');
    bar.style.width = percentage_width;
}

// Shows next question, hides current

function nextQuestion(question_number) {
    /*
    question_number é a próxima questão, aquela que clicamos o botão para ir

    exemplo, se estamos na questão 1

    current_question_number = 2 - 1 = 1
    question_number = 2

    se estamos na questão 2

    current_question_number = 3 - 1 = 1
    question_number = 3

    */

    var current_question_number = question_number - 1; //question_number é a próxima questão

    var question_number = question_number.toString(); //transforma em string para poder ser lido no getElementById
    var current_question_number = current_question_number.toString(); //transforma em string para poder ser lido no getElementById

    document.getElementById('question-' + question_number).style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('question-' + current_question_number).style.display = 'none';

}

// Previous question button

previous2.addEventListener('click', function() {
    previousQuestion(1);
    shrinkProgressBar('16.67%');
})

previous3.addEventListener('click', function() {
    previousQuestion(2);
    shrinkProgressBar('33%');
})

previous4.addEventListener('click', function() {
    previousQuestion(3);
    shrinkProgressBar('50%');
})

previous5.addEventListener('click', function() {
    previousQuestion(4);
    shrinkProgressBar('66.67%');
})

previous6.addEventListener('click', function() {
    previousQuestion(5);
    shrinkProgressBar('83.33%');
})

// Shrink Progress Bar

function shrinkProgressBar(percentage_width) {
    var bar = document.getElementById('progress_bar');
    bar.style.width = percentage_width;
}

// Shows previous question, hides current

function previousQuestion(question_number) {

    var current_question_number = question_number + 1;

    var question_number = question_number.toString();
    var current_question_number = current_question_number.toString();

    var el = document.getElementById('question-' + question_number);
    var el2 = document.getElementById('question-' + current_question_number);

    el.style.display = 'block';
    el2.style.display = 'none';

}
```

```css
#question-2,
#question-3,
#question-4,
#question-5,
#question-6 {
    display: none;
}

#progress_bar {
    background-color: #018fd0;
    width: 16.67%;
    height: 10px;
    transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
                    <form class="questions_box formulario" action="enviar-landing-page-rsa.php" method="post">

                        <div id="question-1">
                            <h3>Qual o nome do seu filho(a)?</h3>

                            <div class="input-formulario">
                                <i class="far fa-user"></i>
                                <input required type="text" name="nome_crianca_rsa" id="nome_crianca_rsa" placeholder="Digite o nome do(a) aluno(a)" oninput="checkStudentsName()">
                                <span id="error-nome-crianca-rsa"></span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="text-center mt-3">
                                <input type="button" id="submit1" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" value="Enviar Resposta" style="display: none;" />
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div id="question-2">

                            <h3>Qual a data de nascimento do seu filho(a)?</h3>

                            <div class="input-formulario">
                                <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>
                                <input required type="text" name="data_nascimento_crianca_rsa" id="data_nascimento_crianca_rsa" placeholder="Digite a data de nascimento do(a) aluno(a)" oninput="checkNumber()" maxlength="2" />

                                <!-- se ao invés de onkeypress, colocar onkeyup, vai aceitar preenchimento de caracteres que não números -->
                            </div>

                            <div class="text-center mt-3">
                                <input type="button" id="submit2" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" value="Enviar Resposta" style="display: none;" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="text-end mt-3">
                                <input type="button" id="previous2" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" value="Pergunta Anterior" style="display: block;" />
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div id="question-3">

                            <h3>Complete a frase com aquilo que lhe é mais importante: "Eu quero que meu filho ..."</h3>
                            <input type="radio" class="radioButton" name="objetivo" id="question-3-answer-a" value=1 required> Aproveite melhor o tempo que passa no computador ou celular.<br>

                            <input type="radio" class="radioButton" name="objetivo" id="question-3-answer-b" value=2> Melhore as notas de uma ou mais matérias na escola.<br>

                            <input type="radio" class="radioButton" name="objetivo" id="question-3-answer-c" value=3> Aumente sua criatividade.<br>

                            <input type="radio" class="radioButton" name="objetivo" id="question-3-answer-d" value=4> Dê os primeiros passos para se tornar um brilhante engenheiro no futuro.<br>

                            <div class="text-end mt-3">
                                <input type="button" id="submit3" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" value="Enviar Resposta" style="display: none;" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="text-end mt-3">
                                <input type="button" id="previous3" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" value="Pergunta Anterior" style="display: block;" />
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div id="question-4">
                            <h3>Qual o nome do(a) responsável?</h3>

                            <div class="input-formulario">
                                <i class="far fa-user"></i>
                                <input required type="text" name="nome_responsavel_rsa" id="nome_responsavel_rsa" placeholder="Digite seu nome" oninput="checkFathersName()">
                                <span id="error-nome-responsavel-rsa"></span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="text-center mt-3">
                                <input type="button" id="submit4" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" value="Enviar Resposta" style="display: none;" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="text-center mt-3">
                                <input type="button" id="previous4" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" value="Pergunta Anterior" style="display: block;" />
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div id="question-5">
                            <h3>Qual seu whatsapp?</h3>

                            <div class="input-formulario">
                                <i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i>
                                <input required type="text" name="celular_rsa" id="celular_rsa" placeholder="Digite seu celular" maxlength="10" onkeypress="return maskMobile(event)" oninput="checkMobile()">
                                <span id="error-celular-rsa"></span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="text-end mt-3">
                                <input type="button" id="submit5" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" value="Enviar Resposta" style="display: none;" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="text-end mt-3">
                                <input type="button" id="previous5" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" value="Pergunta Anterior" style="display: block;" />
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div id="question-6">

                            <h3>Qual seu telefone residencial?*</h3>
                            <h6>*Para caso não consigamos contato no celular.</h6>

                            <div class="input-formulario">
                                <i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i>
                                <input required type="text" name="telefone_rsa" id="telefone_rsa" placeholder="Digite seu telefone residencial" maxlength="9" oninput="checkTelephone()">
                                <span id="error-telefone-rsa"></span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="text-end mt-3">
                                <input type="submit" id="submit6" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" value="Enviar Resposta" style="display: none;" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="text-end mt-3">
                                <input type="button" id="previous6" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" value="Pergunta Anterior" style="display: block;" />
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </form>
                    
                        <script type="text/javascript">
        
        function checkStudentsName() {
            var countName = document.getElementById('nome_crianca_rsa');
            var errorName = document.getElementById('error-nome-crianca-rsa')

            countName.value = countName.value.replace(/[0-9]/g, ''); // Remove numbers
            if (countName.value.length < 3) { // 0 chars entered
                errorName.innerHTML = "O nome precisa ter ao menos 3 caracteres."
                document.getElementById('submit1').style.display = 'none';
            } else {
                errorName.innerHTML = "";
                document.getElementById('submit1').style.display = 'block';
            }
        }

        function checkNumber() {
            var countAge = document.getElementById('data_nascimento_crianca_rsa');
            countAge.value = countAge.value.replace(/\D/, ''); // Remove caracteres que não sejam números

            if (countAge.value.length == 0) { // 0 caracteres digitados
                document.getElementById('submit2').style.display = 'none';
            } else {
                document.getElementById('submit2').style.display = 'block';
            }
        }

        document.querySelectorAll('.radioButton').forEach(item => {
            item.addEventListener('click', event => {
                checkObjective();
            })
        })

        function checkObjective() {
            if (document.getElementsByName('objetivo').value == '') {
                document.getElementById('submit3').style.display = 'none';
            } else {
                document.getElementById('submit3').style.display = 'block';
            }
        }

        function checkFathersName() {
            var countName = document.getElementById('nome_responsavel_rsa');
            var errorName = document.getElementById('error-nome-responsavel-rsa')

            countName.value = countName.value.replace(/[0-9]/g, ''); // Remove numbers
            if (countName.value.length < 3) { // 0 chars entered
                errorName.innerHTML = "O nome precisa ter ao menos 3 caracteres."
                document.getElementById('submit4').style.display = 'none';
            } else {
                errorName.innerHTML = "";
                document.getElementById('submit4').style.display = 'block';
            }
        }


        function checkMobile() {
            var countMobile = document.getElementById('celular_rsa');
            var errorMobile = document.getElementById('error-celular-rsa');

            if (countMobile.value.length < 8) {
                errorMobile.innerHTML = "O celular precisa ter ao menos 8 dígitos";
                document.getElementById('submit5').style.display = 'none';
            } else {
                errorMobile.innerHTML = "";
                document.getElementById('submit5').style.display = 'block';
            }
        }

        function maskMobile(evt) {

            var tecla = evt.keyCode;

            if (tecla >= 48 && tecla <= 57) {

                var tel = document.getElementById("celular_rsa");

                var tam = tel.value.length;

                if (tecla != 8) { // 8 = espaço (em hexadecimal)
                    switch (tam) {
                        case 0:
                            tel.value = "(" + tel.value;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            tel.value = tel.value + ")";
                            break;
                        case 9:
                            tel.value = tel.value + "-";
                            break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        }

        function checkTelephone() {
            var countMobile = document.getElementById('telefone_rsa');
            var errorMobile = document.getElementById('error-telefone-rsa');

            if (countMobile.value.length < 8) {
                errorMobile.innerHTML = "O telefone precisa ter ao menos 8 dígitos";
                document.getElementById('submit6').style.display = 'none';
            } else {
                errorMobile.innerHTML = "";
                document.getElementById('submit6').style.display = 'block';
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Where does it hide questions initially via CSS? If so, I'd start from there

Comment: You can read this is my explanation. Sorry, but I only posted the question because I tried to solve it. This answer was rather obvious and didn't help at all.

Comment: Well, my question remains, since all your javascript code does is hides/shows 1 question at a time. What hides the rest of the questions is not answered, the provided code shows ALL the questions at once.

Comment: No, the provided code show one question at a time. You can read more about style.display.

Comment: Just create a reproduceable snippet so we can see what shows and what doesn't. The code you've provded hides nothing until user interaction. Which means this part of the code is not the issue, the other part that is not shown here, that supposed to hide everything at the beginning is the issue.

Comment: You solved the issue. Thank you very much. I was so obsessed that the error was in Javascript that I forgot to look at the CSS.

And on it was: #question-2,
#question-3,
#question-4,
#question-5 {
     display: none;
}
See that there was no #question-6

And thank you also for the snippets tip, that's where I discovered my mistake. I'm new here and will use them for my next questions.